# How to read only integer values from serial data in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, split, integer, serial-port

I am reading a spectral data using serial port in python. I just want to read the integer raw values from the output (as shown in figure)… I want to read the integer value in between colon (:) and \r\n.....[serial output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rvuy.png)

Comment: Can regex help you?

Comment: "*I just want to read the integer raw values from the output*" -- What is read is called *input*. Since the input looks like ASCII text (as indicated by the **\r** and **\n** control characters), there are no "*integers*". You will have to read each complete line of text, then extract and convert each text string of digits to a binary value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`string.split()` can easily do this for you. Split on the `" : "` part, take element 1, split again on the `"\r\n"` part and take element 0.

```py
data = b" ADC0/F1 : 1201\r\n"

nr = data.split(b" : ")[1].split(b"\r\n")[0]

print(nr)
print(int(nr))
```